Recursively sum child's nominal to parent, on dynamic level parent-child structure
I have data that looks like this
I  am trying to sum the Nominal column to each respective parent, so it will looks like this
I provided the SQL script for the data :
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account](
    [AccountSeq] [bigint]  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [ParentAccountSeq] [bigint] NULL,
    [AccountCode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [AccountName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Nominal] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL
) 

INSERT [dbo].[Account] ([AccountSeq], [ParentAccountSeq], [AccountCode], [AccountName], [Nominal]) 
VALUES 
    (1, NULL, N'101', N'AKTIVA LANCAR', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
    ,(2, 1, N'10101', N'KAS', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
    ,(3, 2, N'1010101', N'KAS KECIL (IDR)', CAST(10000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
    ,(4, 2, N'1010102', N'KAS KECIL ($$$)', CAST(15000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
    ,(5, 1, N'10102', N'BANK', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
    ,(6, 5, N'1010201', N'BCA PKU AC: 220.391', CAST(20000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
    ,(7, 5, N'1010202', N'BCA PKU AC: 220.279', CAST(25000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
    ,(8, 1, N'10104', N'PIUTANG USAHA', CAST(30000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
    ,(10, 1, N'10105', N'PIUTANG PROYEK', CAST(40000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
    ,(11, NULL, N'201', N'HUTANG JANGKA PENDEK', CAST(50000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
    ,(12, NULL, N'301', N'MODAL', CAST(60000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))

The last SQL query I tried:
WITH cteTest AS (
    SELECT
    AccountSeq,
    ParentAccountSeq,
    AccountCode,
    AccountName,
    CAST(Nominal AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Nominal
    FROM
    [Account]
    WHERE
    ParentAccountSeq IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
    a.AccountSeq,
    a.ParentAccountSeq,
    a.AccountCode,
    a.AccountName,
    CAST((a.Nominal + cte.Nominal) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Nominal
    FROM
    [Account] a
    INNER JOIN [cteTest] cte ON cte.AccountSeq = a.ParentAccountSeq
)
SELECT
*
FROM
[cteTest]
ORDER BY
AccountSeq

Please can anyone help me to solve this?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question. You've provided sample data as DDL and DML, which is great (thank you), but please take a moment to convert your expected results into a markdown table.

"Please can anyone help me to solve this?" What is it you specifically need help with? Why isn't what you have working as you expect?

This fiddle might help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/EyOZ396s

You're almost there, but think what data you're actually getting and what you need. You want to add all children amounts to the parent, right now you're adding parent amount to the children which makes no sense

For this task we can collect all children for every account and then sum nominals to parent account.

Anchor part of recursive query.
We take all accounts from table as root.

Recursive part.
Recursive collect children's (thru link to parent), children's of children and so on. Column rootAccount is the same for all children on every branch of the tree.
Output of recursive query below.

Aggregate nominal by rootAccount.


Here lvl and accs columns - for debug and clarity.
See example
Your source data



AccountSeq
ParentAccountSeq
AccountCode
AccountName
Nominal




1
null
101
AKTIVA LANCAR
0.00


2
1
10101
KAS
0.00


3
2
1010101
KAS KECIL (IDR)
10000.00


4
2
1010102
KAS KECIL ($$$)
15000.00


5
1
10102
BANK
0.00


6
5
1010201
BCA PKU AC: 220.391
20000.00


7
5
1010202
BCA PKU AC: 220.279
25000.00


8
1
10104
PIUTANG USAHA
30000.00


10
1
10105
PIUTANG PROYEK
40000.00


11
null
201
HUTANG JANGKA PENDEK
50000.00


12
null
301
MODAL
60000.00



Recursive query
with r as(
  select 0 lvl,AccountSeq rootAccount,AccountSeq incAccount,Nominal
  from tAccount
  union all
  select lvl+1 lvl,r.rootAccount,t.AccountSeq incAccount,t.Nominal
  from r inner join tAccount t on t.ParentAccountSeq=r.incAccount
)
select a.*,t.sumNominal,accs
from tAccount a
left join(
   select rootAccount,sum(nominal)sumNominal
     ,string_agg(cast(incAccount as varchar),',') accs
   from r
   group by rootAccount
  ) t on a.AccountSeq=t.rootAccount





AccountSeq
ParentAccountSeq
AccountCode
AccountName
Nominal
sumNominal
accs




1
null
101
AKTIVA LANCAR
0.00
140000.00
1,2,5,8,10,6,7,3,4


2
1
10101
KAS
0.00
25000.00
2,3,4


3
2
1010101
KAS KECIL (IDR)
10000.00
10000.00
3


4
2
1010102
KAS KECIL ($$$)
15000.00
15000.00
4


5
1
10102
BANK
0.00
45000.00
5,6,7


6
5
1010201
BCA PKU AC: 220.391
20000.00
20000.00
6


7
5
1010202
BCA PKU AC: 220.279
25000.00
25000.00
7


8
1
10104
PIUTANG USAHA
30000.00
30000.00
8


10
1
10105
PIUTANG PROYEK
40000.00
40000.00
10


11
null
201
HUTANG JANGKA PENDEK
50000.00
50000.00
11


12
null
301
MODAL
60000.00
60000.00
12



Details.
Recursive query output before aggregate
with r as(
  select 0 lvl,AccountSeq rootAccount,AccountSeq incAccount,Nominal
    ,cast(AccountSeq as varchar(100)) path
    ,AccountName
  from tAccount
  union all
  select lvl+1 lvl,r.rootAccount,t.AccountSeq incAccount,t.Nominal
    ,cast(concat(path,',',cast(t.AccountSeq as varchar(100)))as varchar(100)) path
    ,t.AccountName
  from r inner join tAccount t on t.ParentAccountSeq=r.incAccount
)
select * from r order by rootAccount,lvl;




lvl
rootAccount
incAccount
Nominal
path
AccountName




0
1
1
0.00
1
AKTIVA LANCAR


1
1
2
0.00
1,2
KAS


1
1
5
0.00
1,5
BANK


1
1
8
30000.00
1,8
PIUTANG USAHA


1
1
10
40000.00
1,10
PIUTANG PROYEK


2
1
6
20000.00
1,5,6
BCA PKU AC: 220.391


2
1
7
25000.00
1,5,7
BCA PKU AC: 220.279


2
1
3
10000.00
1,2,3
KAS KECIL (IDR)


2
1
4
15000.00
1,2,4
KAS KECIL ($$$)


0
2
2
0.00
2
KAS


1
2
3
10000.00
2,3
KAS KECIL (IDR)


1
2
4
15000.00
2,4
KAS KECIL ($$$)


0
3
3
10000.00
3
KAS KECIL (IDR)


0
4
4
15000.00
4
KAS KECIL ($$$)


0
5
5
0.00
5
BANK


1
5
6
20000.00
5,6
BCA PKU AC: 220.391


1
5
7
25000.00
5,7
BCA PKU AC: 220.279


0
6
6
20000.00
6
BCA PKU AC: 220.391


0
7
7
25000.00
7
BCA PKU AC: 220.279


0
8
8
30000.00
8
PIUTANG USAHA


0
10
10
40000.00
10
PIUTANG PROYEK


0
11
11
50000.00
11
HUTANG JANGKA PENDEK


0
12
12
60000.00
12
MODAL



fiddle

with additional details info "path" you provided, i now understand about cte better.
thank you very much!

Reverse the recursion and group by accs to get hierarchy of totals
WITH cteTest AS (
    SELECT
    AccountSeq,
    ParentAccountSeq,
    AccountCode,
    AccountName,
    CAST(Nominal AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Nominal
    FROM
    [Account] a
    WHERE not exists (select 1 from [Account] b where a.AccountSeq =b.ParentAccountSeq)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
    a.AccountSeq,
    a.ParentAccountSeq,
    a.AccountCode,
    a.AccountName,
    cte.Nominal
    FROM
    [Account] a
    INNER JOIN [cteTest] cte ON cte.ParentAccountSeq = a.AccountSeq
)
SELECT AccountSeq,
    ParentAccountSeq,
    AccountCode,
    AccountName,
    sum(Nominal) nom
FROM
[cteTest]
GROUP BY
    AccountSeq,
    ParentAccountSeq,
    AccountCode,
    AccountName
ORDER BY 
    AccountSeq


This solution was hard for me to follow. I had to break it down to understand how it worked. https://dbfiddle.uk/9eskf6iE

A good answer contains a good explanation in addition to a solution.

i now realized what i did wrong. that's why i never get it right, my understanding of cte recursive is inverted.
your solution definitely help me, thank you very much!

@HendriIrawan,   you did a great job in your fiddle. You are welcome.
